# 404 NOT FOUND when use locales

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am using middlleware to switch between languages English an Arabic

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ApplyLocale
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $segments = collect($request->segments());

        $locale = $segments->first();

        if (! in_array($locale, config('app.locales'))) {
            $locale = 'ar';
            app()->setLocale($locale);
            $segments->prepend($locale);

            return redirect($segments->implode('/'));
        }

        app()->setLocale($locale);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and in helper.php I use this to switch between

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
function switchLocaleUrl()
{
    $locale = config('app.locale');

    if ($locale === 'ar') {
        return '/en/' . collect(Request::segments())->splice(1)->implode('/');
    }
    return '/ar/' . collect(Request::segments())->splice(1)->implode('/');
}
```

and in view I use :

```
  <li><a href="{{ switchLocaleUrl() }}"><i class="hvr-float-shadow"></i> {{ config('app.locale') === 'en' ? 'عربي' : 'ENGLISH' }}</a></li>
```

but when I go to url localhost/myproject/ar 
the error 404 NOT FOUND happened

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo mistake in your middleware handler

use `config('app.locale')` instead of `config('app.locales')`

Comment: it does not  change

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an Array containing the available languages in **config/app.php**

   'languages' => array('en', 'fr', 'de', 'es')
2. Add this code to **filters.php**

App::before(function($request)
    {

```
 if ( in_array(Request::segment(1), Config::get('app.languages')) ) {

    Session::put('locale', Request::segment(1));
    return Redirect::to(substr(Request::path(), 3));

 }
  if ( Session::has('locale') ) {

    App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));

  }

});
```